# Load only a column of file MATLAB

Tags: matlab, file-io

I am interested only in a column of a file, (I can not load the file normally, the rows have different size of columns)

So

```
>load('file.txt');
```

is not working, but I want to retrieve the first column in that file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use textscan to load it and skip the other columns by using an asterick.

```
fid = fopen('file.txt');
textscan(fid, '%*s%*s%s');  % loads only the third column
fclose(fid);
```

This assumes there are exactly three columns in your file.  If you have many more columns, you will want:

```
fid = fopen('file.txt');
    twocols = textscan(fid,'%*s%*s%s%*[^\n]');
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: so `>> fid = fopen('spamtrn.txt');
>> textscan(fid, '%s');
>> fclose(fid);` would read only first column?

Comment: No, you need an entry for each column.  So in my example, I assume you have 3 columns of strings and you only want the last one.